# Нужна помощь в ПАЙТОНЕ

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Смотрите,как сделать мне некое хранилище куда будут поступать данные,в виде пайтановского файла,вся суть в том,что даже если я выйду из пайчарми,данные должны сохраниться.
Элементарно,хочу что бы переменная а,каждый раз увеличивалась когда я нажимаю кнопку 'пуск'.
Только начиню познавать все тонкости данного занятия.
Благодарю за ответ!

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, что вы пробовали сделать для реализации своей идеи.

Answer (score 5):

*Смотри,как сделать мне некое хранилище куда будут поступать данные,в виде пайтановского файла,*.

Смотрю, но вижу, что "пайтановский файл" (.py - файл) это никоим образом не средство "хранилища данных".

*вся суть в том,что даже если я выйду из пайчарми,данные должны сохраниться.*

А вот это назвается сохранение информации во внешнем файле. Описано в любом учебнике по Python, который рекомендую все-таки прочитать, прежде чем начинать что-то строчить в "пайчарм".

*Элементарно, хочу что бы переменная а, каждый раз увеличивалась когда я нажимаю кнопку 'пуск'.*

Какую кнопку "пуск"? Если при запуске самого скрипта, то это значит, что в нем должно быть чтение из файла переменной, увеличение ее на 1 и перезапись ее в тот-же файл. Если речь идет об экранной форме, в которой присутствует кнопка "Пуск", то это значит, что  с соответствующем виджетом-кнопкой надо связать функцию-обработчик, которая выполнит то, что я описал выше. И то и другое - "элементарно", как и просили.

*Только начиню познавать все тонкости данного занятия.*

Похоже, не оттуда начали. Начние с книжек, а не с видосиков и каких-то статеек в интернете. А то так и будете с каждым элементарным вопросом на сайт бегать, да толку от этого будет мало.

P.S. Как новичку на сайте подсказываю, что отвечающие тут люди (некоторые) могут вам годится в деды и иметь опыт программирования больший, чем возраст ваших родителей. Поэтому школьная фамильярность тут не в почете.

Comment: спасибо,понял,учту

Comment: "опыт программирования больший, чем возраст ваших родителей"... та ладно! ;)

Comment: что то мне кажется тут нету людей с 50 летним стажем XD

Comment: Ну, с 40 годами  стажа -  точно есть.